# I can be 22 intrinsically and have a possible range between 22 and 96 (44 at the start)

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

I can be formed in many ways, and four parts are always involved.  Sometimes the formation can happen with all four parts at once, but sometimes some parts come later than the others.  The highest scenario (let's call this scenario I1) happens with all four parts at once, is 22 intrinsically, and can be affected by four factors<sup>[1]</sup> resulting in a possible range between 22 and 96 (at the start it is 44).  Every other scenario has zero involved in some way.  All of the scenarios have non-zero intrinsic and possible range values, and can be affected by the same four factors.

More than one of me can be formed in many ways, and seven parts are always involved.  Sometimes the formation can happen with all seven parts at once, but sometimes some parts come later than the others.  The highest scenario (let's call this scenario M1) happens with all seven parts at once, is 24 intrinsically (34 if not for a limitation), and can be affected by five factors<sup>[2]</sup> resulting in a possible range between 74 and 152 (at the start it is 98, 100, or 118).  All of the scenarios have zero involved in some way and have non-zero intrinsic and possible range values.  All of the scenarios in which the formation happens with all seven parts at once can be affected by the same five factors.  The scenarios in which some parts come later than the others can only be affected by four out of the five factors (those factors being A, B, C, and D).

Notes:

[1] Let's call the four factors A, B, C, and D.  Scenario I1 will be affected by none, one, or two of the factors, never three or four of them.  It may also be affected by more than one occurrence of the same factor.

[2] Let's call the five factors A, B, C, D, and E (where A, B, C, and D are the same as in [1]).  Scenario M1 will be affected by one, two, or three of the factors, never four or five of them.  It may also be affected by more than one occurrence of the same factor.

What am I?

Hints:

> 1. When scenario I1 is 22, it is not affected by any of the factors.  When it is 96, it is affected by factors A and D.  When it is 44 at the start, it is affected by factor C.
>
> 2. When scenario M1 is 74, it is affected by factor E.  When it is 152, it is affected by factors A, D, and E.  When it is 98 at the start, it is affected by factors C and E.  When it is 100 or 118 at the start, it is affected by factors A, C, and E.
>
> 3. For all of the scenarios (for both me and more than one of me), the value never changes after the formation occurs.  This means that the formation may occur at the start or after that.
>
> 4. When a scenario has "zero involved in some way", zero will be involved once or twice, and it's not related to how many times the digit 0 appears in the value.
>
> 5. I can be formed up to three times per [REDACTED], but more than one of me can only be formed once per [REDACTED].
>
> 6. When the formation of more than one of me happens with all seven parts at once, it is always affected by factor E.
>
> 7. **Any** formation that occurs at the start is always affected by factor C.
>
> 8. This puzzle is related to one of the following categories: entertainment, biology, geography, math/geometry, English/grammar.  The subject of this puzzle has been mentioned on more than one occasion on this site.
>
> 9. No more than one formation occurs at the start, but it is possible for multiple formations to occur simultaneously after that.
>
> 10. When a formation occurs, it doesn't have to be of me or more than one of me - it can be of something else.
>
> 11. "More than one of me" can actually be considered a single thing.
>
> 12. Location/position determines which factors affect a given scenario.

Comment: Can't help but to think that the answer is related to chromosomes

Comment: Is the possible range for "more than one of me" or the "I"?

Comment: That's for "more than one of me", since "I" can be 96 at most.

Comment: Reminds me of Blood Pressure :P

Comment: I hope this isn't a sinusoidal frequency response....!

Comment: @pacoverflow How can the possible range of 74-152 be for "more than one of me" since you first say it's 24 or 34?

Comment: @randal'thor 24/34 is not possible once you take into account other factors.

Comment: what does intrinsically mean here?

Comment: I think it has something to do with sound sampling rates.

Comment: I think it has something to do with computers rather than the biological/medical things most people have been guessing...

Comment: Chemical isotopes?

Comment: So far, none of the guesses as to what this puzzle is about are correct.

Comment: For everything said in the question, I'd think this is some kind of mathematical object...

Comment: Maybe a hint? It would be usefull and it hasn't been solved for almost a week

Comment: Maybe it's some sort of intrinsic function with at least 4 arguments..

Comment: Perhaps something to do with bicycle gear ratios?  I'll have to think a little about it...

Comment: If I saw the answer, would I likely think, "WTF I would have NEVER gotten that," or would I likely think "Oh! Dang! I should have gotten that! I understand completely?"

Comment: @JLee I think most people are likely to think the latter.  For reasons I will not mention, I'm shocked this puzzle hasn't been solved already.

Comment: Will you give a hint- which category is it in, if any? Sports/fitness, science, computing, music, entertainment, technology, biology, geography, astronomy, math/geometry, politics, religion, English/grammar, other?

Comment: Maybe a categorical hint, as mentioned above?

Comment: Can you verifty that this definition of `intrinsic` fits the use in this puzzle? http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intrinsic.

Comment: @tfitzger Yes, the word "intrinsic" is used appropriately.

Comment: reading this puzzle feels similar to reading law

Comment: Does this have something to do with a video game?

Comment: Is calibration involved?

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but are the numbers literal, or do they represent something else?

Comment: @tfitzger The numbers are literal.

Comment: Are the numbers in base 10?  Are the ranges inclusive or exclusive of their endpoints?

Comment: @2012rcampion They are in base 10. The ranges are inclusive of the endpoints.

Comment: Is this possibly something to do with telephone numbers?

Comment: All the hints are, well, horrible, and prove to be more frustrating than the riddle itself, which is a great task. We need a category, please, pretty please, with a cherry on top. See my previous comment on June 13th regarding this. :)

Comment: @JLee When I post the next hint, I'll also eliminate some of the possible categories.

Comment: I think we're getting to a point where this question either needs to be reworded or a self answer needs to be made by the poster. No offense, but I agree with @JLee that this is just too difficult to follow the wording. I've actually been tempted to vote to close as unclear, but I don't think this quite fits that mold.

Comment: @tfitzger I think this puzzle became much more difficult when I added various details after the original posting.  I added them to close some loopholes that people could potentially use to say the numbers aren't correct.  It is probably easier to just focus on scenarios I1 and M1 and not worry about the other scenarios.

Comment: The problem is that the original puzzle is already confusing enough and then you add a whole bunch of "hints" that are just as confusing. They serve more to confirm guesses rather than point towards the direction people should be taking. Even the most recent hint is not too useful since it primarily just eliminates a list of topics that the answer does not relate to without addressing which of the (infinitely) remaining topics it could actually relate to. I'm actually surprised this hasn't been closed to be perfectly honest.

Comment: Regarding Hint 5: Is "[REDACTED]" a time scale?

Comment: @Wayne_Yux No that doesn't have to do with time.

Comment: It seems to me that, because the answer is in-our-faces obvious, the question was overly obfuscated in order to keep it from being too simple. The question has an overly jargon-y feel, an the hints don't do anything to make it easier. In fact, they add to the confusion. Could you tweak at least hint eight to give an actual category, and not a subset of the infinite list of categories that we know it's not?

Comment: Can you please give us the answer?

Comment: Where is McMagister when you need him?  I wonder if he can solve this.

Comment: Can't shake the feeling it's music related. 440hz/A, etc. etc.

Comment: I am thinking more about biology. Maybe some protein complex thing (would make sense, regarding the formation out of different parts). But I can't make any sense of the numbers...

Comment: It's been two and a half months since the last answer was posted. Can you please just add an answer instead of adding new, incredibly vague hints that do nothing to help?

Comment: I got it!  Please wait as I formulate the answer.

Comment: Excellent puzzle by the way.

Comment: @McMagister Thanks, I was starting to think people might consider this one of the worst puzzles on the site!  If only you hadn't taken a hiatus, this puzzle would have lasted only 1.5 hours instead of 3 months!

Comment: This was another pretty awesome puzzle ruined by some really confusing hints. It's a shame no one figured it out quickly and everyone ended up getting really antsy. :)

Comment: @BaileyM I was surprised this puzzle lasted so long because I had seen various "I wonder if this is related to Scrabble" type of comments posted on other puzzles.  I figured people would think about Scrabble for this one.  There are a few hints I could have posted to make this significantly easier, but I decided to keep it challenging since people frequently complain about puzzles here being solved in less than an hour.  :-)

Comment: Next time, try staying away from all the [REDACTED] nonsense. :P

Comment: @BaileyM That was more of a joke hint in response to JLee's "law" comment.  :-)  If I had said "game" instead of [REDACTED], it definitely would have been too easy!

Comment: Either way, this one was a "smack-on-the-forehead" kind of puzzle. Here I was, investigating how .22 caliber bullets were made...oy.

Comment: Incredible puzzle! The fact that you had to bring the great @McMagister out of retirement to solve it (how did you track him down anyway?) says a lot :-D It looks _way_ more complicated than it really is. I've been waiting for this one to be solved for _so_ long!

Comment: @randal'thor I really didn't think it would last past the first few revisions.  All the later details/hints made it seem a lot more complicated.  Now I need to come up with a puzzle that McMagister can't solve in less than a few hours.  ;-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am a

> QUIZ

The four parts are

> letters (scrabble tiles)

Sometimes the formation can happen with all four parts at once, but sometimes some parts come later than the others.

> This is referring to putting down all four scrabble tiles, or forming the word from existing scrabble tiles already on the board.

22 intrinsically

> QUIZ's base scrabble score is 22

four factors

> Double word score, triple word score, double letter score, triple letter score

possible range between 22 and 96 (at the start it is 44)

> Q=10 U=1 I=1 Z=10, total of 22.  With triple word score and double letter score, I double Q or Z, resulting in a score of 32, and triple it to 96.  If QUIZ is the first word played, it must cover the starting tile which is a double word score, for 44 points.

Every other scenario has zero involved in some way.

> The blank tile worth zero points, which will be important later.

All of the scenarios have non-zero intrinsic and possible range values, and can be affected by the same four factors.

> This should be obvious by now.

More than one of me can be formed in many ways, and seven parts are always involved.

> QUIZZES, seven letters

Sometimes the formation can happen with all seven parts at once, but sometimes some parts come later than the others.

> Same thing as above.

The highest scenario (let's call this scenario M1) happens with all seven parts at once, is 24 intrinsically (34 if not for a limitation)

> QUIZZES has a base score of 34, but there is only 1 Z tile, so a blank tile (worth zero points) must be substituted in place of a Z.

five factors

> The fifth factor, E, is the 50-point bonus for using all 7 tiles in your hand.

possible range between 74 and 152 (at the start it is 98, 100, or 118)

> Minimum score of 74 is achieved by using only the 50 point bonus.  The maximum score of 152 uses a double letter score on Z and a triple word score for 102 points, plus 50 points bonus.  If QUIZZES is the first word played, it must cover the starting tile for double word score, and may cover an additional double letter score as well.

All of the scenarios in which the formation happens with all seven parts at once can be affected by the same five factors. The scenarios in which some parts come later than the others can only be affected by four out of the five factors (those factors being A, B, C, and D).

> Fairly obvious given that factor E only works if you played seven tiles at once.

Comment: Holy crap thank you so much. I can rest a little bit easier tonight.

Comment: Great job, I'm glad I found you - I knew you could figure it out!  :-)  You are officially the King of Puzzling!

Comment: It should be noted that even though this answer was posted almost 3 months after I posted the puzzle, McMagister had been inactive and hadn't seen the puzzle until I contacted him on another forum on August 12.  It took him only **one hour** to solve this puzzle!

Answer (score 12):

I think the answer is

> Recorded Music

My reasoning:

> The initial sampling rate for CDs was 44kHz. Human hearing can pick up up to 20kHz, so the real necessary sampling rate (intrinsic) is 40kHz by the Nyquist theorem. DVDs and Blurays use a sample rate of 96kHz, but that's not the highest it can go.

As in for the second part, which is much more ambiguous

> The loudness of breathing is roughly 20-30 dB. Talking is about 60 dB. Most music begins around the range of 60-70 dB in the low range. 150 dB is the rough peak of Rock music. 160 dB will physically rip your eardrums appart. So it depends on what song was recorded.

Sources:

> http://www.gcaudio.com/resources/howtos/loudness.html http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Examples_of_sound_pressure

Comment: +1 for a nice try.  But the answer I'm looking for precisely fits the numbers in the question.

Comment: bummer, I'll keep the gears turning

Comment: Note the wording on the question changed a bit

Answer (score 5):

Not a complete answer, but maybe others can build on it.

You are

> a GENOME.

*In one scenario, I am 44 at the beginning (but less than that intrinsically) and have a maximum of 96. Every other scenario for me has zero involved.*

> This is the number of genes in some particular kind of genome (human?)

*More than one of me always has zero involved. In one scenario, it is 24 intrinsically (34 if not for a limitation), and when everything is taken into consideration, the possible range is between 74 and 152.*

> Genetic engineering/modification?

*No scenario has a beginning, intrinsic, minimum or maximum of zero. When zero is involved, it is involved in some other way.*

> A genome with zero genes wouldn't be much of a genome!

And the hint:

> *More than one of me can only occur unnaturally* - "more than one of me" = "meme", and a meme is supposed to be an artificial social version of a gene.

**Aggie Kidd**, help me out here!

Comment: The answer isn't related to genomes, but +1 since I like how you came up with "meme" (although that's not what the hint is referring to).

Comment: @pacoverflow Damn, "I can be formed in many ways, and four are always involved" made me feel sure that this was about DNA/chromosomes, and was halfway through writing an answer before I read your comment here on rand al'thor's.